# Adding data to firestore database with firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

---

data i get from external api is not saved in firestore database

but the record I added as last name xxxxx is successful
wait db.collection('coins').add({lastName: 'xxxxxxx'}) this works but the code below does not

```
exports.firestoreKaydet = functions.firestore
  .document("/users/{userId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    await db.collection("coins").add({ lastName: "xxxxxxx" });

    fetch(
      "https://api.coinecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (data) => {
        data.forEach(async (coin) => {
          await db.collection("coins").add({
            name: coin.name,
          });
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `async/await` within a `forEach()` loop, see "[JavaScript: async/await with forEach()](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)" and "[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)".

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
exports.firestoreKaydet = functions.firestore.document('/users/{userId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    
    try {
        
        // db shall be defined as admin.firestore()

        await db.collection('coins').add({ lastName: 'xxxxxxx' });

        const response = await fetch("https://api.coinecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true");

        const data = response.json();

        const promises = [];
        data.forEach(coin => {
            promises.push(db.collection('coins').add({
                name: coin.name
            }));
        });

        return Promise.all(promises);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return null;
    }
    
});
```

---

**UPDATE:** After helping you debugging, it appears that `fetch` was not installed. Install it in the `functions` directory as follows

```
npm install node-fetch
```

then put the line below in the `index.js` file:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
```

Comment: thanks but same problem persists

Comment: Do you see any error in the Google Cloud Logging console? In addition there was a copy/paste error in my answer: it should be `promises.push(...)` and not `p.push(...)`.

Comment: the error does not appear and the firestore database is empty

Comment: How do you define `db`? Can you show your entire `index.js` file , with the module imports at the top.

Comment: now i added all index.js

Comment: db.collection('coin').add({ last name: 'xxxxxxx' });
Do you understand why this works and why the other code does not?

Comment: So the Cloud Function correctly writes to Firestore. What do you get if you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json()));`. Where do you look for errors?

Comment: firebase-debug.log doesn't show any errors and terminal doesn't show any errors either

Comment: But where do you look to see the errors? You need to use the Google Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query

Comment: resource.type="cloud_function" resource.labels.function_name="firestoreKaydet" resource.labels.region="us-central1"                                                                                                            
{
insertId: "tp2lv6f7o1sv2"
labels: {1}
logName: "projects/borsa-app-f6921/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
receiveTimestamp: "2022-12-19T16:39:30.247959964Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "DEBUG"
textPayload: "Function execution took 1388 ms, finished with status: 'error'"
timestamp: "2022-12-19T16:39:29.966611847Z"
trace: "projects/borsa-app-5"
}

Comment: there doesn't seem to be anything wrong here

Comment: "Function execution took 1388 ms, finished with status: 'error'" => This is an error. Can you debug with adding `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json()));`to see what the fetch call returns?

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice at this, I couldn't see where the log is written

Comment: firebase functions:log --only firestore by running save command in Terminal D
2022-12-19T15:53:28.573032032Z D firestoreSave: Function execution started
2022-12-19T15:53:28.658742Z ? firestoreSave: ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Comment: I learned something new thanks to you

Comment: okkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

```
 const { request } = require('express');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 admin.initializeApp();
 const db = admin.firestore();


 exports.firestoreKaydet=functions.firestore.document('/users/{userId}')
      .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {


  const response = await 
   fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets? 
 vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true');

const data = response.json();;

 const promises = [];
 await data.forEach(async coin => {
    promises.push(db.collection('coins').add({
        name: coin.name
    }));
 });

 return Promise.all(promises)
 });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).